# How do I loop through an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-insert

The problem I am having is getting the `INSERT INTO` Mysql statement to fire during each loop of the `while` statement.

It is correctly looping according to the `echo` coming back the correct amount of times, however the `INSERT INTO` is only working the 1 time.

Basically the question is: "How do I loop through this SQL `INSERT statement` using a PHP or SQL statement"

Thanks in advance

EDIT : Being an absolute doughnut I didn't realize I had set a primary key for the orderID, which was working all along. It was just not allowing duplication of the orderID .

Thanks for the help

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['checkout']))
{
$sql="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE userID =".$_SESSION['user'];
$query= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $querys= "INSERT INTO `orderdetail`(`orderID`, `selectionID`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),{$row['cardchoiceID']})";
              $performit = $conn->query($querys);
                echo("testing");
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should do a "for each" loop.

Comment: Curious mix of `Object Orientated` and `Procedural` code - but the `Insert` statement appears to update with the id from the previous insert - is that really the desired effect?

Comment: You might be inserting it multiple times, but you're setting your orderID to the last orderdetail ID after the first loop

Comment: The last_insert_id takes the orderID from a table called orders so they match with other items inside the same order. so in this orderDetails table there is all the items ever ordered, with a order id next to it. Even with that just as a random number it still only produces 1 inserted item into the table despite being 4 in the cart

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` always takes the last insert ID from the last INSERT that was done. Which means that it's no longer your order ID after the first pass.

Comment: Generate the orderID first then just use that instead of LAST_INSERT_ID.

Comment: @aynber even so, it should still insert a value into the table , even if it was the wrong one.(tried just putting a normal number in also) but it doesnt, it just inserts 1 out of the 4 that are in the cart whilst continuing to loop the echo testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize the approach by inserting from a select statement (call it a "migration" from one table to another):

```
"INSERT INTO orderdetail(selectionID, orderID)
  SELECT selectionID,orderID FROM cart WHERE userID =".$_SESSION['user'];
```

Reference: [Mysql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: You beat me to the answer! @Ka_lin :D

Comment: I was typing fast, happens to me allot :P, sheers and happy coding

Comment: I don't think he want's `orderID` to auto-increment as I'm guessing its a foreign key and an order was inserted in some code above this.

Comment: @cmorrissey yes thats correct , i cant have the orderID different from the orders table as that connects it to the user and all the items for the same order will have the same orderID

Comment: I have updated my answer to insert the same orderID from the the cart table so that they won't be different

Comment: This seems to be where i want to go, except orderID comes from a different table called orders, and selectionID comes from cart table, how would i use those SELECT's as the values for the inserts?

Answer (score 0):

Ka_lin's answer is a fine one but your order didn't store the user/cart detail? I see no relation between them

Normally the flow of cart is

1. User add some items to the cart (cart has id)
2. User checkout and cart become an order (generate an order id with items from the cart) with

   `insert into orders(cart_id,item_id,item_qty,item_price,create_datetime)
   select cart_id,item_id,item_qty,item_price,now() from carts;`
3. then update cart_status to marked this cart as 'finished' to make sure we create a new cart when this user returned

   `update carts set cart_status = 'ordered' where user_id = {$user_id};`
4. Go on and process the order!

===============

Edited after saw an OP comments

Maybe this way will work for you

1. Have a `order_header` (store generic info - like order_type,addresses,timestamp and users) and `order_detail` (store items/products related info) tables
2. Insert a carts info into `order_header` to generate an order_id
3. Obtain order_id from `order_header` with `select order_id from order_header where user = {$user_id} and status = 'new'`
4. insert item/product detail into `order_detail` with `insert into`order_detail`(order_id,some columns here...) select ('{$order_id}',some columns here...) from carts where user = {$user_id};`
5. then update the cart_status to 'ordered' - that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Had set orderID to primary key. cant have duplicates